# pre save middleware in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-middleware

i am first time using pre save middleware and getting a bit confusion in it.

It runs perfectly fine and also my save method is getting executed eventhough i am not calling the next()

case 1

```
tourSchema.pre('save', function () {
  console.log('first middleware is getting called');
})
```

But when i do like this when next is declared inside the function params but i don't call the next() it hangs there and the save method is not getting executed

case 2

```
tourSchema.pre('save', function (next) {
  console.log('first middleware is getting called');
});
```

But as soon as i call the next() it gets executed

case 3

```
tourSchema.pre('save', function (next) {
  console.log('first middleware is getting called');
  next()
});
```

so i only want to know what's the wrong with the second case . In this i have only and only this pre middleware .
How defining the next inside the function params can matter, the save method should also be executed in the second case since i don't have any second pre middleware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mongoose uses [kareem](https://github.com/vkarpov15/kareem) library to manage hooks.

`kareems` makes use of the `length` property of your hook function to determine whether `next` is defined as an argument or not.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/length

Your first function has no arguments, `kareem` will assume this is a sync function

```js
const firstFunction = function () {
  console.log('first middleware is getting called');
})
console.log(firstFunction.length) // this will output 0
```

Your second function has 1 argument, the `kareem` library will see your function accept `next` arguments. It will pass a callback and execute it in the `next` function. Since `next` is never called, that callback will be never called.

```js
const secondFunction = function (next) {
  console.log('first middleware is getting called');
})
console.log(secondFunction.length) // this will output 1
```

Comment: I have added more explanation to the answer

Answer (score 0):

thammada's answer perfectly explains your issue, I just want to add and say you can actually use an async function to escape the obligation to call next()

> Pre middleware functions are executed one after another, when each middleware calls next.

```
`const schema = new Schema(..);
 schema.pre('save', function(next) {
   // do stuff
   next();
 });`
```

> In mongoose 5.x, instead of calling next() manually, you can use a function that returns a promise. In particular, you can use async/await.

```
schema.pre('save', function() {
  return doStuff().
  then(() => doMoreStuff());
});
```

[Read more about it here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html#pre)