# difference between calling of pre-middleware with next and without next

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-middleware

i wan't to know what's the difference between calling the middleware with next and without next

example without next 
All middleware run perfectly fine without next also

```
tourSchema.pre('save', function () {
  console.log('second middleware is getting called');
  const currentDoc = this;
  const slugDocument = slugify(currentDoc.name, { lower: true });
  this.slug = slugDocument;
  console.log('after addition of slug', this);
});
tourSchema.pre('save', function () {
  console.log('third pre middleware is called');
});
tourSchema.pre('save', function () {
  console.log('4th middleware is getting called');
});
```

with next there seems to be no difference with calling next or without next. So whats the main difference between these two.

```
tourSchema.pre('save', function (next) {
  console.log('second middleware is getting called');
  const currentDoc = this;
  const slugDocument = slugify(currentDoc.name, { lower: true });
  this.slug = slugDocument;
  console.log('after addition of slug', this);
  next();
});
tourSchema.pre('save', function (next) {
  console.log('third pre middleware is called');
  next();
});
tourSchema.pre('save', function (next) {
  console.log('4th middleware is getting called');
  next();
});
```

Comment: does someone know the difference between two ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pre save middleware in mongoose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61466548/pre-save-middleware-in-mongoose)